# redeclare const variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, constants

One of the key features of `const` in `JavaScript` is that the `const` variable [cannot be redeclared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

However, in this code that is grabbed from [this link](https://github.com/t-mullen/simple-signal):

```js
signalServer.on('discover', (request) => {
  const clientID = request.socket.id // clients are uniquely identified by socket.id
  allIDs.add(clientID) // keep track of all connected peers
  request.discover(Array.from(allIDs)) // respond with id and list of other peers
})
```

Every time a new client connects to the server via a socket, a new `const clientID = request.socket.id` is created.

So the `clientID` variable is created more that one time even though it is a `const`.

How is that possible?

Comment: It's only being declared once in that scope (the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable name can only exist once in a *scope*. (Redeclaring one with `var` doesn't cause an error, doing so with `let` and `const` does).

Each call to a function creates a new scope.

There's still only one instance of that variable in that scope.

Comment: I am curious, whilst this throws an error in chrome dev tools console:  `const x = 1;` (press enter) and then on next line `x = 2;`  (press enter - returns error `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`), this does not `const x = 1;` (press enter) and then on next line `const x = 2;`  (press enter - the value of `x` is now `2` and has been redeclared).

Comment: @user1063287 it’s to be useful inside the console. If you do that in a function it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

It's only being declared once in each scope that you have it, if clientID was in the outer scope, let's say along with signalServer then it would work the way you think it did

Answer (score 0):

this constant only exists in the block of the callback function. after the function is executed, the constant is unloaded from memory.

Answer (score 0):

`const` are block scoped [const - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

In the snippet, every time the callback function is called after `discover` event is triggered, a new execution context is created for the callback function.

Scope for `const clientID` is limited within the nearest curly braces, where it can be assigned only once at the time of declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I understand it correct, `const` variable is unique in each `execution context`?

Comment: @royaahmadi yes. that's correct. `const` and `let` both have similar variable scope.

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know variables in functions are always temporary if they are declared in the function scope. So even though it's a const it's still temporary since it's declared inside a function. You however would not be able to declare a different variable with the same identifier. so saying const x and later on saying let x isn't possible. If you had identified the const x outside of the function scope you wouldn't be able to set a variable with the same identifier in the function scope.

Comment: "If you had identified the const x outside of the function scope you wouldn't be able to set a variable with the same identifier in the function scope." — You can. This is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: "as far as I know variables in functions are always temporary if they are declared in the function scope" — It's possible to create a closure that extends the life of a variable in a function to be the life of the whole program.

Comment: const x = 10;

const func = function()
{
    x = 20;
};

func();

this does not work

Comment: Reassigning an existing constant is not the same as redeclaring it. `const x = 20` (which redeclares it) would work.

Comment: Now that I didn't know. Seems kinda weird. Is it best to just not use const in a function then? Because this is pretty confusing.

Comment: Shadowing is not specific to constants, and constants are great in functions and elsewhere.